# How do I use the elements of a list as inputs in my function definition?

Tags: python, list, function

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math
```

## The list of Energy values for the different states

```
s = [1,-1]
Energy = []
List2 = []



for _ in range(900):
    List = [random.choice(s), random.choice(s), random.choice(s), random.choice(s)]
    E = -(List[0]*List[1]+List[1]*List[2]+List[2]*List[3]+List[3]*List[0])

    List2.append(List)
    Energy.append(E)


Energy = list(dict.fromkeys(Energy))


print(Energy)
```

## All permutations of 1,-1.

```
a = np.array(List2)


b = np.unique(a, axis=0)
print(b)
```

## The Partition Function

```
def Z(E,T,N):
sum = 0
for i in range(0,N):
    sum = sum + math.exp(-E[i]/T)
print(sum)
return sum

Z(Energy,1,3)
```

## Probabilities

```
for E in Energy:
def p1(E,T,N):
    return math.exp(-E/T)/Z
```

The last part is where I'm struggling. I am trying to use the elements of Energy as inputs for the
the probability function, but I'm getting an error.

```
p1(Energy,1,3)
```

when I run the above line of code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

Comment: Maybe you want `[p1(E, 1, 3) for E in Energy]`?  Defining `p1` in a loop doesn't make sense; you want to *call* it in a loop (like in a list comprehension, which will give you a list of the results).

Comment: So something like:

def p1(E,T,N):
    for E in Energy:
        return math.exp(-E/T)/Z
?

Comment: nope, just exactly like what I said.  Use the definition of `p1` you already have, but don't define it inside a loop.  Instead call it in a list comprehension (which is a type of loop).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole list Energy to your function instead of one element

Change this:

```
 p1(Energy,1,3)
```

To this:

```
p1(E,1,3)
```

Your complete code will be like this:

```
def p1(E,T,N):
    return math.exp(-E/T)/Z

for E in Energy:
    p1(E,1,3)
```

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError " unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'function' ". Am I supposed to have an input for the E?

Comment: Write this `Z(E,T,N)` instead of `Z` in math.exp(...)